# Best way to help currencies plugin's performance when doing calculations

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I made an app using currencies plugin to represent money, it introduces 3 domain classes, `Money`, `Currency` and `ExchangeRate`.

here's the `Money` domain class:

https://github.com/ricardojmendez/grails-currencies/blob/master/src/groovy/cr/co/arquetipos/currencies/Money.groovy

Just for the sake of easier explaining, lets just say that I have 2 classes: `SalesOrder` and `OrderItem`.

SalesOrder:

```
class SalesOrder {


       static hasMany = [orderItems:OrderItem]

       List<OrderItem> orderItems
       String customer
       def getTotal(){
           Money total = Money.getInstance("0 USD")
           orderItems.each{
                total+=it.getTotal()
           }
           total
       }

}
```

OrderItem:

```
class OrderItem{



       static belongsTo = [salesOrder:SalesOrder]
       static embedded = ['price']

       Money price
       int quantity
       String itemName

       def getTotal(){
           price * quantity
       }

}
```

The goal is to get a total for each `SalesOrder`, since I don't think I can write a query for `Money` for calculating total

(because exchangeRate and currency are both involved in each Money object):

I could have one money that's defined as "amount: 25, currency: USD" and another "amount: 500, currency: JPY", if I just query the amount part, the result will be off, since it doesn't convert the currency into the same one.

, I was forced to run loops through each and every `OrderItem` in `SalesOrder`, as you can imagine the performance was so bad it took me nearly 18 seconds to get a total for 30 `SalesOrder`s. (I was able to lower this down to 9 seconds after adding "orderItems fetch: 'join'" in static mapping of SalesOrder. but 9 seconds is still too much)

This plugin isn't very popular so I couldn't find a case where anybody who ran into things like this, so if you have experience in dealing with this kind of problem, please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

why not? Something like

```
def total = OrderItem.withCriteria( uniqueResult:true ){
  projections{ sum 'price.amount' }
  eq 'salesOrder', salesOrder
}
```

could do the trick

Comment: because currency/exchange rate is involved, not all money is saved in the same currency, conversion has to be performed for every money object that has a different currency. 

I could've saved one "25 USD" and one "5000 JPY", if you just simply query the amount, the total will be off by a lot.

Comment: ok, I got it. I'd add a new field to store price in one currency, say in `$` and save all other currency values by re-calculating in `$`. Thus you can always get the dollar amount and re-calc it to the target currency. It's not really straight-forward but you barely have any other option here